# Tomato Firmware on Linksys WRT54GS Firmware Version: v1.50.6

Tags: router, firmware, tomato

I'm trying to install Tomato and get "Upgrade Failed". Any idea why it's failing?

Comment: Try resetting to factory default, http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT54GS/v5-v6/1.50.6/FacDef.htm, and reboot before trying again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install DD-WRT first and then use its upgrade section in the web interface to covert to Tomato.

Comment: No you don't.  I've upgraded directly.